# Sorting out an array List using Collections

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I want to use the Comparator object of the Collections framework to sort out an ArrayList by an specific attribute.

I have an ArrayList called `measureEviArray` this array contains objects type `MeasureEvi`.

The class `MeasureEvi` has an attribute called `mCoordenate` which corresponds to a PointF data type.

```
public class MeasureEvi {

private int mIndex;                             //  
private int mOrderIndex;
private int eIndex;                             // 
private TextView mTag;                          // 
private PointF mCoordenate; 
}
```

What I want is to sort out that array depending on the coordenates given to each object in X (`mCoordenate.x`)

Is it possible to use Collections for this and get an Array Ordenate from the minor to the greatest in X axis?

I was trying to implement this way:

```
 Collections.sort(measureEviArray, new Comparator<MeasureEvi>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MeasureEvi measureEvi, MeasureEvi t1) {
            return measureEvi.getmCoordenate().x.compareTo(t1.getmCoordenate().x);
        }
    });
```

but compareTo is not an Option, cannot resolve method.

Comment: Is `x` an `int`? If so, use `Integer.compare(x1, x2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`x`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PointF.html#x) from [`PointF`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PointF.html) is a `float`, use [`Float.compare(float f1, float f2)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Float.html#compare(float,%20float)):

```
return Float.compare(measureEvi.getmCoordenate().x, t1.getmCoordenate().x);
```

Comment: Do you know if I use this to compare Integer, would it work in android < 4.4, I am getting the following observation: add @Requires API 4.4 KITKAT

Comment: @Juanca If you look at the documentation for [`Integer.compare(int x, int y)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)), you'll see "added in [API level 19](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)", and following that link shows that to be Android 4.4, so no.